# How to make a button look pressed after click in C#?

Tags: c#, button, pressed

I have a button to select a tool and I want to make it look pressed after the user clicks it. I am using winforms and I do not want to use Check Box with Button Appearance. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can do that by changing the BackColor property of the Button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CheckBox with the Appearance property set to Button.